# Content of WKWebview in Uitableviewcell is disappearing on dynamic resizing

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I'm loading my `UITableViewCell` like the following code is showing:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath);
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        Utilities.LogDebug(message: "Load html content");

        if (webViewHeight == 0.0) {
            let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration();
            infoWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration);
            infoWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
            infoWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            cell.contentView.addSubview(infoWebView);

            let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoWebView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoWebView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoWebView, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoWebView, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let bottomContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: infoWebView, attribute: .bottomMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            cell.contentView.addConstraints([height, width, leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomContraint])

            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "assets/html/about", withExtension: "html") {
                let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
                infoWebView.load(urlRequest)
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

After loading the html content I'm determining the size of the content by the following:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if (self.webViewHeight != 0) {
        return;
    }
    self.infoWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            self.infoWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                self.webViewHeight = height as! CGFloat
                let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.infoWebView.frame.width, height: self.webViewHeight);
                self.infoWebView.frame = frame;
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            })
        }

    })
}
```

After determining the size of the content I'm reloading the corresponding cell to apply the new height.

So far this is working! The height of the cell is resized and also the size of the WKWebView.

My Problem is now that the content of the WKWebView is only showing up for a short period of time and then disappearing.

Maybe somebody can see my mistake here.

Comment: there might be an issue with the constraints so try to remove the old ones in the cell in prepareForResue

Comment: Sounds like this class could be useful to you: https://github.com/Vugla/PSHTMLView

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and found that using .none for tableview reload animation solves the issue.

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .none)
```

For anyone who is facing similar issue.